# How can I vertically align this placeholder inside an input="text" form?

Tags: html, css, placeholder

[image: The Problem]

So I am trying to make this look good, but I can't. The problem is that I can't vertically align the text. If someone can help me, I would be very grateful.

Here is the css:

```
#search-bar {
    margin-top: -3%;
    margin-left: 30%;
    width: 40%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    border: 2px solid whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code, so we can help.

Comment: I did @ThanyathonPornsawatchai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by default text in a input in vertically centered.

```
padding-top: 2%;
```

is causing it to be pushed to the bottom.

for a fix i would recommend using a height or also setting padding-bottom to 2%

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without providing any html or css, but it looks like you might be forcing a `height` on your input without changing the `line-height` property.

Comment: I added the css, I am not using any style in the HTML @DavidCarignan

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to create custom input.
And my suggestion is you can achieve it by writing code like this

```css
#search-bar {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
}

body {
  background: #292929;
}
```

```html
<input id="search-bar" placeholder="Some text.." />
```

You can also style placeholder with `::placeholder`

```css
#search-bar {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
}

#search-bar::placeholder {
  color: red;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

body {
  background: #292929;
}
```

```html
<input id="search-bar" placeholder="Some text.." />
```

> **EDIT**

And I would like to suggest you some flexbox too.
Please take a look at this code. We can center the child element in the parent easily with `display: flex` and use `justify-content`, `align-items`

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* this is for horizontal alignment */
  align-items: center; /* this is for vertical alignment */
}

.child {
  background: lightskyblue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```